# Surprising results when reading a bool with std::cin and entering decimal numbers as input

Tags: c++, boolean, visual-studio-2022, iostream, cin

I was learning about `bool` variables. I learned that non-zero values are considered `true`, and when I used `cin` to assign `2` to a `bool`, the result was `true`, as expected. But when I used `0.1`, the result was `false`. Why is that?

I have tried other numbers such as `1.1`, `-1.1` `0.5` `-0.5`. My understanding is that when the absolute value is `>= 1`, then the result is `true`, and otherwise `false`. I don't know if this is correct, but if it is, then how to reconcile it with the "nonzero values are truthy" rule?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's unrelated. OP tries to `>>` a decimal number into a bool.

Comment: The behaviour is as if using `>>` to a `long`, and then the bool is false if the value `0`, or true otherwise.  I.e. the decimal point was the end of input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I learned that non-zero values are considered true

This only applies to the conversions performed in the code, not to `std::cin >>`. How `std::cin >>` reads scalar types is described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get).

For a `bool`, it reads a single `long` value (so it stops reading at `.` if you pass a fractional number). If it's `0`, the result is `false`, otherwise `true`. But if the number is neither `0` nor `1`, it also sets an error flag, which you should be checking:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    bool b = false;

    if (std::cin >> b)
        std::cout << "success, b=" << b << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "failure, b=" << b << '\n';
}
```

For `0` and `1`, this prints `success, b=0` and `...=1` respectively. For e.g. `2` or `-1`, this prints `failure, b=1`.

If you use [`std::boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha), none of that happens, and instead it expects strings `true` or `false` (or others if you use a non-default locale).